# Light switch with time delay turns off instantly (2-3 seconds)

Tags: light, timer

In my stairway, i have a Light switch with time delay. When i press the button the lights turn on, but instantly turn off (in 2-3 seconds). The lights should be turned on for at least 10-15 seconds in order to be able to use the stairs at night.
Please advise.
Many thanks!!

Comment: Make/model of the switch in question? Has it _ever_ worked properly? Did you just install it or has it been here for years? Help us help you!

Comment: Yes it was working properly. It is a standard light switch with time delay. Not sure of the make/model. It was installed before 11-12 years

Comment: Code **requires** the lights stay on forever until turned off; or if a motion sensor until motion ceases and a time delay.  There is no such thing as a "standard switch with time delay", however there are plenty of "specialty switches with time delay that one has no further details about". The fact that you had one, alas, does not make it standard.  Regardless, it might be time to think "motion sensor".

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  that's a bit broad and inaccurate.  There's nothing wrong with adding a timer switch to, e.g., a bathroom light-fan combo so it only runs for a few minutes.

Comment: What country are you in?  And please do open up the box and tell us (on the back of the switch or similar location) what brand, serial/model number, etc.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft We're talking about a stairway.

Answer (score 2):

Since it worked for approximately 11 years (or more) and now does not, I would guess that the time delay depends on a capacitor, and the capacitor has failed.

Given it is mains voltage switching equipment, a whole new switch is probably the right/legal/safe solution, rather than attempting to disassemble and repair something that likely was not designed for disassembly and repair.

Answer (score 1):

Some timer switches have a delay that can be set. Take the cover plate off the box and look at the front of the switch to see if there are any rotary knobs that can be turned (might take a very small screwdriver) or any little levers that can be moved. There may be labeling on it indicating "5 min", "10 min", etc. or there may be some code or (unlikely, but possible) no labeling at all.

Try adjusting this adjuster to see if it makes a difference. If so, it seems someone else did the same and reset the timer to mess with you. If not, or if there's no adjustment option at all, it's most likely that the timer portion of the switch has failed and it's time to replace it.

If you do have to replace it, be sure to turn the power off at the breaker box/consumer unit *before* proceeding any further. Also, be sure to take pictures of the wiring *before* you remove any of it. You don't want to join the crowd of people posting here asking how to put something back together when you have no idea how it was wired before you took it apart. ;)